# How can we use \Drupal class inside Settings.php

Tags: 8

How can we use `\Drupal` class inside the *settings.php* file to load configuration ojects, for example?

```php
$slogan = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('slogan');
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. Settings.php is one of the first files loaded, used to bootstrap the system. The settings are required for bootstrapping. Calling the `\Drupal` class is calling the bootstrapped system, which of course can't be done without loading the settings. So you're in a loop. As leymannx asked, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no config available when settings.php is executed. This is in very early stages of the Drupal bootstrap process and neither the database connection nor the service container is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The *settings.php* file is loaded from [`DrupalKernel::initializeSettings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3AinitializeSettings/9.4.x), which is called from [`DrupalKernel::handle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3Ahandle/9.4.x) before [`DrupalKernel::boot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3Aboot/9.4.x).
This means that when the code in *settings.php* is executed, the dependency injection container hasn't yet initialized, the services aren't yet available, and `\Drupal::config()` would throw an exception about `\Drupal::$container` not yet initialized.

The code in the *settings.php* file can use PHP functions or functions/methods already loaded from the autoloader. The latter aren't guaranteed to function properly.

The purpose of the *settings.php* file is (generally speaking) setting configuration values.
It could read some configuration values from its local variables, for example `$settings['hash_salt']` or `$settings['file_public_base_url']`, but code that would work in a module isn't guaranteed to work in the *settings.php* file.