# How can I check if the redis module is enabled in settings.php?

Tags: 9, installation

I've read [How can I check if a module is enabled?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188322/how-can-i-check-if-a-module-is-enabled) and [How can we use \Drupal class inside Settings.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311397/how-can-we-use-drupal-class-inside-settings-php) and came to the conclusion that I cannot use the module_handler service in settings.php.

How can I check if a module -- in this case the redis module -- is enabled in settings.php?

**Context**

I am using docker for a Drupal 9.4 installation. When I initialize a new container from the image, and I install Drupal (initialize a new database), the redis module isn't initially activated, although present.

This means I cannot initially specify `$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';` in settings.php (it will make the system crash).

I would have like to do

```
$moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
if ($moduleHandler->moduleExists('redis')) {
  $settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';
}
```

Of course this doesn't work and I understand why. But I would like to avoid going into my container to edit settings.php after activating the redis module every time I start a new container.

Comment: It seems like this question is really "How do I use redis as a cache backend at install time?".

Comment: You cannot check if modules are enabled in settings.php, as Drupal has not been bootstrapped when this file is loaded. Usually if you want a module like Redis to be installed on some environments and not others, you use the Config Split module.

Comment: @cilefen It could be it. But, it would be nice if the site would function if the redis module is disabled without the need for editing settings.php again. And I think in general the answer could prove useful for other cache backends (or even other modules).

Comment: @Jaypan thank you I was not aware of this module. If it's not possible to do what I want, then that answers that ;)

Comment: There are some tips here: https://docs.platform.sh/guides/drupal9/redis.html

Comment: @cilefen thank you, I will have to dig deeper in platform.sh to understand fully. I think I will answer my question for now and say it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this precise question is now part of the Redis module:

```
use Drupal\Core\Installer\InstallerKernel;
if (!InstallerKernel::installationAttempted() && extension_loaded('redis')) {
  $settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';
  //etc
}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer at it seems now possible to do it (but I haven't tried it yet).

Answer (score 2):

For the same reasons mentioned in [How can we use \Drupal class inside Settings.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311397/how-can-we-use-drupal-class-inside-settings-php), namely that the Drupal bootstrap process hasn't completed yet, this cannot be done.

see @Jaypan's comment.